# Regular expressions help need pattern {{ * }}

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm terrible with regular expressions! I've never been able to get my head around them.

I am currently using JQuery to get a string of the HTML between two tags.

**What I require**

I need to be able to find all matches of angular style tags like so {{sample}}.

I need an array returned so that I can loop through it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Although I don't have an answer for your question, I recommend [Debuggex](http://debuggex.com) for visualizing your regexs and testing different strings against them.

Comment: use this `\{\{.*?}} regex`

Comment: @AvinashRaj that works but only for the first one... what if there are multiple {{this}} and {{that}} I need an array of ['this','that']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use capturing groups to capture the text which are present inbetween `{{` and `}}`

```
> var str = "what if there are multiple {{this}} and {{that}}"
undefined
> var re = /\{\{(.*?)}}/g;
undefined
> var s = []
undefined
> var m;
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
... s.push(m[1]);
... }
2
> s
[ 'this', 'that' ]
```

Comment: Ha... I just realised this problem today... Thank you! Very good answer.

Comment: Just tried it... it works beautifully. I really need to spend some time learning RegEx

Comment: yep, a common thing exists on all the programming languages is Regex. It would make your life easier. http://www.regular-expressions.info/ best site for learning regexes.